# Docker PostgreSQL change database encoding to UTF-8

Tags: docker, postgresql, docker-compose

I want to run via docker-compose a postgres container which has COLLATE and CTYPE 'C' and database encoding 'UTF-8'. But this looks to be impossible.

This is the part on the docker-compose.yml:

```
database:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
        - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
        LC_COLLATE: C
        LC_CTYPE: C
        LANG: C.UTF-8
```

And this is the log output:

```
The database cluster will be initialized with locales.
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
  COLLATE:  C
  CTYPE:    C
  MESSAGES: C.UTF-8
  MONETARY: C.UTF-8
  NUMERIC:  C.UTF-8
  TIME:     C.UTF-8
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "SQL_ASCII".
```

I must have the database encoding in UTF-8 and the COLLATE and CTYPE in 'C' and **not** 'C.UTF-8' as otherwise a dependend application cannot connect.

I didn't find anything in any documentation or anywhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to conjoin two pieces of the puzzle here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/app-initdb.html

initdb, teachs you how to pass encoding information to the database creation function.

The postgres official Docker image, states you can pass options, to initdb:

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Ergo, the answer would be something like:

```
database:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
        - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
        POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: '--encoding=UTF-8 --lc-collate=C --lc-ctype=C'
```

Or similar arguments. I ignored the lang option, as this is not an official "pass this flag to postgres" option on the man page (the first link I included).

My tests did not run this using docker compose, it was on the command line using the -e option. This is the exact same concept however; "environment" in docker compose is -e on the command line. To wit:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

> --env , -e        Set environment variables

Test #1 with only the password env set:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test postgres:latest
```

Here's the output of the default run:

```
postgres@cbf23636dabc:~$ psql
psql (13.4 (Debian 13.4-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Test #2, with environment variables set as above in the suggested docker compose only on CLI:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS='--encoding=UTF-8 --lc-collate=C --lc-ctype=C' postgres:latest
```

And then the output:

```
postgres@b6b80c876f3e:~$ psql 
psql (13.4 (Debian 13.4-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Note also, the section on the official Postgresql Docker image page, where it describes initialization scripts. This is something you may look into as well.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time working with PostgreSQL. I wasn't aware of how database creation works in detail.

Comment: No problem! Postgres is a bit of a bear, but I'd definitely suggest finding a GUI to work with it if you can. There's several options, although my personal favorite is pgAdmin. Open source.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the approach above, and another issue I encountered was that the default Debian base that comes with the official Postgres Docker image doesn't have any other languages installed.

```
# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

To set another language, e.g. Chinese, it was necessary to run e.g. `localedef -i zh_CN -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias zh_CN.UTF-8`.

Then setting the environment variables worked.

Because of this need, it seems that the default Postgres image doesn't satisfy all the needs, and it would be better to build a custom image, as documented [in this post](https://blog.csdn.net/Tuine/article/details/119144974).

```
FROM postgres
RUN localedef -i zh_CN -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias zh_CN.UTF-8
ENV LANG zh_CN.utf8
```

Then `docker build -t your-custom-image-name .`

Then you can use the custom image in your `docker-compose.yml` instead of the official postgres image, without needing to set any environment variable in addition.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually combine the build into docker compose:

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres-de
    build: ./pg-docker-config  # a Dockerfile must reside in this directory
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PW}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB} #optional (specify default database instead of $POSTGRES_DB)
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS='--locale=de_DE.UTF8'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    # volumes:
      # - /postgres/dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The Dockerfile in `./pg-docker-config` looks like this

```
FROM postgres:latest
RUN localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8
ENV LANG de_DE.utf8
```

Make sure to delete your existing database volume(s) before composing again by running ...

```bash
docker compose down --volumes
```

... or else you will see this message, and the database will **not** initialize the locale settings

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```

Now you can launch the container(s) with only one command :)

```bash
docker compose up -d
```